# How to put object in query? Angularjs resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

For example I have something like this:

```
{
  status: {
    text: "New",
    date: "22.06.12"
  }
}
```

Factory to interact with RESTfull lookes like

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .factory('Orders', Orders);

    Orders.$inject = ["$resource"];
    function Orders($resource){
        return $resource('Orders/:id', {id: '@id'});
    };

})();
```

And I want to find all records with status.text = "New"

```
 $scope.orders = Orders.query({status:{text:"Tru"}});
```

not work at all

```
$scope.orders = Orders.query({status[text]:"Tru"}});
```

return all records....

How to put object property to query?

Comment: How do you implement the actual filtering in your API?

Comment: I using SailsJS RESTful
And something like
 Orders.query({text:"text"}}
works normaly,
question how to use object as creteria for seraching

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you trying to interact with no-RESTful backend with $resource service. $resource is designed for REST, for other situations is better to use standard $http-service, like that:

```
$http({
  url: 'http://ololo.com',
  method : 'get',
  params : {status: 'tru'}
}).success(function(response){
  $scope.filteredOrder = response;
});
```

Use 'data' for 'post'.

Comment: I using Restful..
But even in such way

$http({ url: 'http://ololo.com', method : 'get', params : { status: {text: "New"} } })

would not work...

Comment: I'd made some refactoring in my answer. Looks like problem is on backend, check there, are all of params came correctly. Remember, some backends, whitch not supports native JSON (like Apache or some Python-based), requires to convert JSON to string. Try to send params this way: params : JSON.stringify({status: 'tru'})